# Join com várias tabelas

Tags: join

Tenho o código abaixo funcionando perfeitamente, mas preciso incluir mais uma tabela nesta consulta e não estou conseguindo.

O campo a se incluir vem da tabela `entvenc` e seu nome é `TIPODOC`, sendo que o campo em comum desta tabela com a tabela `nfentra` é chamado `DOCUMENTO`.

```sql
Select nfentra.NUMERO As NumeroNF, 
       nfentra.CNSCADUSU as UsuarioCad, 
       nfentra.RAZ_SOCIAL As RazaoSocial, 
       base_nfetpent.DESCRICAO as TipoEntrada, 
       nfentra.VALORTOT As Valor, 
       nfentra.FECHAMENTO as Fechamento 
       
From base_nfetpent 
right Join nfentra On base_nfetpent.CODTIPO = nfentra.TIPOENT 
Where FECHAMENTO BETWEEN "2021-12-01" and "2022-01-04" and nfentra.RAZ_SOCIAL like '%ouro verde%'
order by FECHAMENTO
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta você acrescentar a junção desta tabela àquela que já existe:

```sql
Select nfentra.NUMERO As NumeroNF, 
       nfentra.CNSCADUSU as UsuarioCad, 
       nfentra.RAZ_SOCIAL As RazaoSocial, 
       base_nfetpent.DESCRICAO as TipoEntrada, 
       nfentra.VALORTOT As Valor, 
       nfentra.FECHAMENTO as Fechamento 
       entvenc.TIPODOC as TipoDocumento --campo desejado
From base_nfetpent 
right Join nfentra On base_nfetpent.CODTIPO = nfentra.TIPOENT 
right join entvenc on entvenc.DOCUMENTO = nfentra.DOCUMENTO --junção adicionada
Where FECHAMENTO BETWEEN "2021-12-01" and "2022-01-04" and nfentra.RAZ_SOCIAL like '%ouro verde%'
order by FECHAMENTO
```